How come the PC1 loadings in my RDA are all zero?
I have a dataset of some 130 ponds that were sampled for species presence and environmental variables. I have tried to run an RDA (based on the Vegan package) to find which habitat variables have a big impact on the species community. I first used a stepAIC() which ended up with this model:
rda_small = rda(formula = data_RDA$Bufo_bufo + data_RDA$Ichthyosaura_alpestris + data_RDA$Lissotriton_helveticus + data_RDA$Lissotriton_vulgaris + data_RDA$Pelophylax2 + data_RDA$Pelophylax1 + data_RDA$Rana_temporaria + data_RDA$Triturus_cristatus 
                ~ Structure + 
                  Macrophyte_Rich + Fila_Algae + Shadow_BL + Shallow_BL + 
                  Oxygen + Conductivity, 
                data = data_RDA)

The resulting ordiplot was really strange
ordiplot of the RDA
so I had a look at the loadings of PC1 in the summary()
Biplot scores for constraining variables

                   RDA1 PC1
Structure        0.4124   0
Macrophyte_Rich  0.1098   0
Fila_Algae      -0.4592   0
Shadow_BL       -0.2397   0
Shallow_BL       0.6925   0
Oxygen          -0.2774   0
Conductivity    -0.2474   0

Obviously something went wrong here. I have no idea what could have caused the PC1 loading to be zero.
I have tried scaling and centering the data beforehand, then went back and tried without centering and scaling and the result was the same.
I used a correlation matrix beforehand to make sure not a single variable fell outside a range of -0.4, 0.4 so i wouldn't have any multicollinearity.
I'm kind of assuming there is this really silly mistake that I'm overlooking but if so I really can't find it.
I didn't know what would be the best way of sharing my data so someone could replicate the problem, so here is a link to the csv file:
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VdgGzPsJ44FJkPeI_2ht_okMxaQJRDnA/view?usp=sharing)
Any insights would be welcome!
